# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found. Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compile a simple map display on in my activity, but the app keeps closing. This is my first time working with an API in Android Studio. Here is my complete manifest code. because when I debug the code it shows API key not found.
Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection">

    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
   
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/blind"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:roundIcon="@drawable/blind"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ObjectDetection">
        <activity android:name=".Navigation.MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".Navigation.GestureDetect"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".Navigation.Navigation"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Reminder.NotificationMessage"
            android:exported="true" /> 
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <receiver
            android:name=".Navigation.RebootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the complete error after debugging the code:-

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 11755
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.Navigation.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #75: Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class fragment
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:528)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:910)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #75: Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #75: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):1)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):24)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):7)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.logInitialization(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.ba(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):5)
        at eu.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@222413050@22.24.13 (040406-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:627)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zze.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzav.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@ 
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:9)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1561)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:737)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2758)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.Navigation.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:273)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7227)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7218)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get [api_key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key) and declare in AndroidManifest.xml just like shown on the error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection">

    <uses-sdk />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
   
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/blind"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:roundIcon="@drawable/blind"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ObjectDetection">
        <activity android:name=".Navigation.MapsActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".Navigation.GestureDetect"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".Navigation.Navigation"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".Reminder.NotificationMessage"
            android:exported="true" /> 
        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <receiver
            android:name=".Navigation.RebootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: but i really don't know how to declare and where to declare? I am working with first time with an API.

Comment: @RishiFf I edited. You can see that line starts with <meta-data you have to add that line. Change YOUR_API_KEY to your api key.

Answer (score 2):

**generate google api key**

1. import the code  your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
2. Create google api key [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGTG1l7yin4)
3. Enter the Key you got in the value field

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/api_key" />
```